# How can I load function in JS before I call it the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am creating a megamenu and it works fine until I try to delay the slideDown. I use jQuery. The code for slideUp and slideDown is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).delay(500).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("fast");
           $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

When I refresh the page and hover over the ".dropdown" element it slides down without any delay. However, when I hover over it again, it delays just fine, as if I called it when i hovered over it the first time.
Same is true for each menu button (do each ".dropdown" element) separately.
I thought that fault lays in $(document).ready(), so I waited for the whole page to load, but that didn't help.
Do you have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Let me show you a fragment of my menu. It also uses bootstrap.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">OLEJE </a>                    
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                         <li class="col-sm-3">
                              <ul>
                                   <li class="dropdown-header" style="color:#F96211">Syntetyczne</li>
                                   <li class="divider"></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Oleje silnikowe 0W30</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Oleje silnikowe 0W40</a></li>
                              </ul>
                         </li>
                    </ul>                    
            </li>
</ul>
```

I stripped it down, so it just shows the basic skeleton.

Comment: Use `.stop()` and also `.not('.in .dropdown-menu')` is hard to say it's correct without seeing a minimal HTML code sample

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's DOM ready's fault.
Without going much into details (since I cannot test your code) here's how I would write the above

```js
jQuery(function($){ // DOM ready. $ alias secured.

    $(".dropdown").hover(function(evt) {

       var mEnt = evt.type==="mouseenter";
       $(this).toggleClass('open')
              .find('.dropdown-menu')
              .not('.in')  // without seeing your HTML I'm not sure about this line
              .stop()
              .delay(mEnt?500:0)
              .slideToggle("fast");

    });          

});
```

Comment: I basically replaced my code with yours leaving the part you didn't change unchanged (so slideUp part) and now when I hover it the first time it shows, then slides up and then it seems like the js started, so like before when I hover over it the second time, it works as it supposed to. Still not the first time around though. I'll edit the question to put som html.